# IE7: tricks/plugins for seeing all the html on a page?

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on an app that's sort of a bastardization of old and new tech (ASP/ASP.NET). It's all running in IE7. I'd like to be able to right click, View Source and actually see all the html that I'm seeing with my eyes. For example, I have a bit of text in the middle of the page that's in a table. I right click directly on that bit of text and "View Source" and the text isn't in the HTML that I'm looking at. There's no line break or special characters. It's a single piece of text like ABC123. Yet ABC123 isn't in the HTML that I see when I view source.

Is this just something that I'm stuck with? If not, how can I get to the HTML that I want? The app won't run in FF so Firebug is out of the question. I've tried a few developer toolbars for IE but have found them to be flawed at best, not working at worst. It's just very frustrating; I want to make a little change to a style of a TD and I have to go through way too much work just to see if I like it (because of the complex way that the HTML is generated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)
- Use IE8 (with its developer tools) in compatibility mode.
- MS created a developer toolbar for IE7 (sort of like Web Developer FF extension): http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en
- Temporarily add a link with an onclick handler to dump document.outerHtml into a `<pre>`

Comment: 1) tried it, not a good option because of the inserted js 2) not an option, don't want my dev env to be out of sync with team 3) that thing doesn't work well

Comment: option 4 might be what I have to do, I'd forgotten about that little trick

Comment: a temporary link with an onclick handler seems to me to be the only 100% sure way to get this to work, so that's why this is the answer

Answer (score 3):

When developing in IE I use the IE developers toolbar:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

It will allow you to see rendered HTML on the page, and allow you to drill down and select specific elements that you want to see. There are various highlighting functions, and you can trace styles back to their source.

It's not the be-all and end-all of developer toolbars, but for those times I can't use Firefox / Firebug it does the job over other solutions I have tried

Comment: +1 I was just going to post that... I've used that toolbar and it seems very similar to Firebug, so I don't know why it shouldn't work.

Comment: tried it before, doesn't work on my setup (or doesn't work very well); I un-installed it after about 10 mins of trying to get it do find element by click

Comment: what about it didn't work? Sometimes you need to adjust some of the advanced settings in IE to get it to work. The easiest way to tell IE is not setup correctly is if you cannot see ANY elements in the left most of the 3 panels

Comment: First problem is that it won't work in my dialog-ish window that I need to see the html in; this app is full of these kind of windows. Can't see history, can't get to menus etc. View source is about the only thing I have.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that this window is a popup and because of that I can't get to any toolbars.

Answer (score 1):

[IE7 Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) gives a right click and "View Generated Source" option.

Comment: Sounds good, but when I click "View Generated Source" nothing happens. Hmm. Posted it as a bug: http://forum.ie7pro.com/viewtopic.php?pid=19364#p19364

Comment: Holy crap it has a downloads window! sweet

Comment: And ten minutes later I uninstalled it. The downloads never connected. Uninstalled and they connected immediately. Something wrong with it, it might be becuase I'm behind a proxy, I dunno.

Comment: Hard to imagine why this would be downvoted though... seems to be exactly what I need (except for the bugs)

Comment: I just installed the latest version and I am able to View Generated Source to Notepad++ with no issues. I am not behind a proxy. Can you test on another machine?